# [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl492695080.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #79): crc64255f1d4b618a9a90.PNMessagingService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

  
1>Deployment failed to pixel_5_-_api_31.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
THIS IS THE EROOR AFTER UPDATING THE GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES. Please help me out in this regard
```

Are anyone facing the issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided says:

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value
> for android: exported be defined when intent filters are present

According to the official documentation of android:

> If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains activities,
> services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must
> explicitly declare the android:exported attribute for these app
> components.

You can try to add `android:exported="true"` to your **PNMessagingService** class. If this class is a third-party class you use, you need to update the third-party Nuget package you use to the latest version.

For more details, you can refer to: [Safer component exporting | Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)